# NSUserDefaultsで背景色を保存する方法とゲームクリア条件のコードの書き方を教えてください。

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift2

プログラミング初心者です。
今趣味でゲームを作っていてわからないことがいくつかあり質問させていただきました。

下の4色はボタンになっています。(今度5色に増やす予定です。)
各色ボタンを押すごとにタッチしたマス目に押したボタンの色を反映できます。

１
アプリのタスクを切るとまた初めからになってしまいます。
NSUserDefaultsでマス目の色をスマホ本体に保存して、アプリのタスクを切っても続きから始められるようにしたいです。
その場合マス目をタッチするたび保存にすれば大丈夫ですか？
また、色を保存する時はどのようなコードを書けばよろしいでしょうか？

２
すべてのマス目を埋めた時、隣り合ったマス目の色が違う場合のみゲームクリアにしたいです。
隣り合ったマス目の色が一致した場合は何も起こらず、すべての隣り合うマス目の色が違う場合のみ
画面移行し「ゲームクリア」にしたいです。
この場合マス目ごとにTagを振ればよろしいでしょうか？
またこの条件のコードはどのように書けばいいでしょうか？

以上の２点です。
１度に２つもしてしまい申し訳有りません。
この２点は今の自分ではわからないので教えてもらいたいです。

どちらもコードを書いていただくと非常に助かります。
一応今書いてあるコードと画像を載せておきます。

質問がわかりにくくて申し訳有りません。

回答お待ちしています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```swift
         myImageA = UIColor.redColor();
         myImageB = UIColor.greenColor();
         myImageC = UIColor.blueColor();
         myImageE = UIColor.yellowColor();


        myImageView.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView2.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView3.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView4.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView5.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView6.backgroundColor = myImageD

        myImageView8.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView9.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView10.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView11.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView12.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView13.backgroundColor = myImageD
         myImageView14.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView15.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView16.backgroundColor = myImageD

        myImageViewa.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView2a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView3a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView4a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView5a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView6a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView7a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView8a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView9a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView10a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView12a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView14a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView13a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView15a.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView16a.backgroundColor = myImageD

        myImageViewb.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView2b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView3b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView4b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView5b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView6b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView7b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView8b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView9b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView10b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView11b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView13b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView14b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView15b.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView16b.backgroundColor = myImageD


        myImageView2c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView3c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView4c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView5c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView6c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView7c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView8c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView9c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView10c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView11c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView12c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView13c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView14c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView15c.backgroundColor = myImageD
        myImageView16c.backgroundColor = myImageD






    }



    func onClickMyButton(sender: UIButton){


        myImageD = myImageA


        }


    func onClickMyButton2(sender: UIButton){

        myImageD = myImageB

        }


    func onClickMyButton3(sender: UIButton){

        myImageD = myImageC

    }

    func onClickMyButton4(sender: UIButton){

        myImageD = myImageE

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first as UITouch?

        if let touchedImageView = touch!.view as? UIImageView {

            touchedImageView.backgroundColor = myImageD


        }




    }






    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

保存する色が4つあるのでその分forkeyも4つ用意したほうがいいですか？
forkeyが１つだと保存した場所の色がすべて同じ色になってしまいませんか？

Answer (score -1):

*説明量が大量になるので、数日かけて回答していく予定です。*

> NSUserDefaultsでマス目の色をスマホ本体に保存して、アプリのタスクを切っても続きから始められるようにしたいです。

`NSUserDefaults`クラスの使い方を説明します。
まず、`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`で、**シングルトン**（Singleton）として、インスタンスを呼び出します。`NSUserDefaults`にデータを保存するには、

```
defaults.setObject("a text value", forKey: "value")
```

このようなメソッドを送ります。整数値、実数値、`NSDate`インスタンスなど、型によってメソッドが異なりますから、詳しくはクラスリファレンスを調べてください。
`NSUserDefaults`は、適切なタイミングで書き加えられたデータを、ファイルに保存しますが、強制的にファイル保存する必要があるときは、`synchronize()`というメソッドを使います。
`NSUserDefaults`からデータを読み出すには、

```
let theText = defaults.stringForKey("value")
```

というメソッドを使います。これも型によって、メソッドが異なりますから、クラスリファレンスで調べてください。
注意しなければいけないのは、**`UIColor`のインスタンスは、`NSUserDefaults`に保存できない**点です。`NSuserDefaults`に保存可能な型（クラス）は限定的で、保存できないのは、`UIColor`だけではありません。色情報は、整数値や文字列に一対一対応させて置き換えてから、`NSUserDefaults`に保存する必要があります。
一対一対応は、列挙体（`enum`）を使うと便利です。

```
enum Color: Int {
    case White = 0
    case Red
    case Blue
    case Green
    case Yellow

    func color() -> UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .White :
            return UIColor.whiteColor()
        case .Red :
            return UIColor.redColor()
        case .Blue :
            return UIColor.blueColor()
        case .Green :
            return UIColor.greenColor()
        case .Yellow :
            return UIColor.yellowColor()
        }
    }
}
```

白＝0、赤＝1、青＝2、緑＝3、黄＝4という対応をしており、`UIColor`とも対応します。

```
// 色の整数値を取得。
let colorNumber: Int = Color.Blue.rawValue
// 色のUIColorを取得。
let colorValue: UIColor = Color.Red.color()
```

◉*2016/1/28 追記*

今回の件では、8×8=64個のマス目の色情報を保存しなければなりませんから、配列を使って、配列を保存することを考えましょう。
まず、色情報を`Int`値に置き換えた、8×8の二次元配列`matrix`をインスタンス変数とします。

```
var matrix: [[Int]]
```

これを`NSUserDefaults`に保存するには、

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(matrix, forKey: "Matrix")
```

保存した配列を呼び出すには、

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let theArray = defaults.arrayForKey("Matrix") as? [[Int]] {
    matrix = theArray
}
```

`arrayForKey()`の返り値は、Optional型です。アプリの最初の起動などで、`NSUserDefaults`に保存されていないと、`nil`を返します。`nil`チェックと、適切な配列の型へのダウンキャストが必要です。

◉*追記ここまで*

どういうタイミングで`NSUserDefaults`にデータを保存するかは、プログラマの設計（デザイン）しだいで、単一の正解はないと思います。「マス目をタッチするたび保存にす」れば、いちばん心配ないですが、コードが煩雑になり、記述漏れによるバグの発生が起きやすいというリスクがあります。

> すべてのマス目を埋めた時、隣り合ったマス目の色が違う場合のみゲームクリアにしたいです。

そのためには、まず隣のマス目を取得することができるプログラムデータの構造を、設計しなければいけません。現状その設計ができていないので、どうすればいいのか、さっぱりわからない状態になっています。
ふつうに考えれば、8×8のマス目を、二次元配列で表現する設計を思いつきます。先ほどの列挙体`Color`を使って、`Int`型を要素とする8×8の配列を作りましょう。

```
var matrix = [[Int]](count: 8, repeatedValue: [Int](count: 8, repeatedValue: 0))
```

n行m列の要素を、`matrix[m][n]`で取得できますが、隣の要素は、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このように取得できます。（端にあるマス目の場合、隣のマス目がないことがあることには、注意してください。範囲外の配列の要素を参照しようとすると、プログラムがクラッシュします。）

Comment: 自分なりにコードを適切な場所に入れてみたのですができませんでした。

タッチして色を表示させた場所を保存させたいので

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
        
        if let touchedImageView = touch!.view as? UIImageView {
            
            touchedImageView.backgroundColor = myImageD
           
           
            // ユーザデフォルトにスコアを格納。
            let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            ud.setObject(, forKey: "color")
      
        }
        
 これであっていますか？
ud.setObject(, forKey: "color")にはどこを指定してあげればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: @田中まま 質問は、コメント欄にでなく、質問文を更新する形でしてください。なお、メソッドの引数になにも入れてない状態では、赤い警告アイコンが出て、ビルドできませんよね？

Comment: それは申し訳有りませんでした。
メゾットの引数になにを書けばいいかが分からなくて質問しました。
この場合はtouchedImageViewでよろしいでしょうか。
上手く言葉にすることが出来ず申し訳有りませんでした。

Comment: @田中まま `UIColor`が`NSUserDefaults`に保存できないのですから、`UIView`（のサブクラス）も保存できないのでは？と考えるのが、ふつうの発想ですし、じっさいそうです。なにが`NSUserDefaults`に保存できるのかは、`NSUserDefaults`のクラスリファレンスをお読みください。書かれています。

Comment: 直接は保存できないのはわかってます。そこをNSDataに変換してから保存 それをアプリを立ち上げた時にDataから再構築するんですよね？
ですが保存をどのようにするのかが分からないので質問しました。
自分がまだまだ勉強不足なのでよく理解できません。